# What does a short-scope namespace array mean?

Tags: javascript

I have this code snippet:

```
var ns;
(function(namespace, undefined) {
  function privateFunction() { ... };
  namespace.publicFunction = function() { ... };
}((ns = ns || {},
   ns.foo = ns.foo || {})));
```

I understand that undefined makes it really undefined. But how does the namespace array work? Does it bind the global functions and var's to both namespaces?

So we give

```
(ns = ns || {},
 ns.foo = ns.foo || {})
```

as namespace variable. If ns or ns.foo already exists it is instantiated as an empty object. I suppose.

Also, in the code you can see that the private and public functions are ended with `;` when do I use `,` `;` and nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`namespace` is not array, `namespace` is a object that stored in global `ns` object under the key `foo`

```
(ns = ns || {},
 ns.foo = ns.foo || {})
```

This code initialize `ns` and `ns.foo` with empty objects if the are **not** initialized before. Then `ns.foo` comes to the function input as `namespace` variable.

As `ns` is global, all properties of `ns` will be globally accessible. So we can get access to public functions outside the function scope by:

```
ns.foo.publicFunction
```

But the private function will be accessible only in scope where they were defined (and in child scopes). For example we can use `privateFunction` within `publicFunction`, but not without anonimous parent function:

```
var ns;
(function(namespace, undefined) {
  function privateFunction() { console.log('hello') };
  namespace.publicFunction = function() { privateFunction(); };
}((ns = ns || {},
   ns.foo = ns.foo || {})));
ns.foo.publicFunction(); // hello
privateFunction(); //ReferenceError: privateFunction is not defined
ns.foo.privateFunction(); //TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

As for semicolon, a function declaration does not need it, unlike function as a statement:

```
function privateFunction() { ... }
var privateFunction = function(){ ... };
```

Comment: "As `ns` is global, all properties of `ns` will be global too" No, they are accessible only via `window.ns` (or just via `ns` in global scope), not directly via `window`. An advantage you didn't mention, is that `ns.foo.publicFunction` can access `privateFunction` too.

Comment: @Teemu What do you mean "not directly via window"? `var global = 'bar'; (function localScope(){ console.log("i'm global: " + global) })();` - here i has defined global variable `ns` (as in code above) and has got access to it in local scope.

Comment: "... _all properties of `ns`_ ..." will not be global. That's exactly why we have set a namespace ...

Comment: I understand how it works now. `(ns = ns || {},
 ns.foo = ns.foo || {})` will evaluate and instantiate ns and ns.foo and use the last one as parameter. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Gudgip Exactly, and that's possibly a mistake in the code. Most likely (but not necessarily)`ns` is supposed to be the namespace, where the properties should be defined to, not one of its properties.

Comment: @Teemu That's what partly got me confused, it makes no sense that the namespace is instantiated there along with it's properties, I'm glad it's all cleared up now.

Comment: @Teemu i guess each property of `ns` provides separate module namespace